# forbidden attribute error rails 4 Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have a issue with a controller file which i have narrowed down to a method

Controller

```
def create
  @gallery = Gallery.new(params[:gallery])
  if @gallery.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created gallery."
    redirect_to @gallery
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end


private

  def gallery_params
    params.require(:gallery).permit(:name, :gallery, :gamepic)
  end

end
```

the problem is that there is no attr_accessible in the controller or the model

model

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gamepics

  private 
    def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:name, :gallery, :gamepic)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the strong parameters method into Gallery.new instead of params[:gallery].
My understanding of this is that, the hash returned from that method is what should be used anyways. So you'd have:

```
@gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
```

If you only need certain params from your :permit call, just make a new strong params method and use that one.